# PDO not working function

Tags: php, function, pdo

register.php

```
         <?php
include_once "pdo.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
     $user_pw = hash("sha256", $_POST['password']);
$params = [
                'pcode' => $pcode,
                'password' => $user_pw,
                'name' => $_POST['name'],
                'phone' => $_POST['number'],
                'grade' => $_POST['grade']
                ];
sql($db, "INSERT INTO member (pcode, password, name, phone, grade) VALUES (:pcode, :password, :name, :phone, :grade)", array($params));
}
?>
```

pdo.php

```
try {
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME.";charset=utf8", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  // PDO fetch docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Simple function to handle PDO prepared statements
function sql($db, $q, $params, $return) {

  // Prepare statement
  $stmt = $db->prepare($q);
  // Execute statement
  $stmt->execute($params);
  // Decide whether to return the rows themselves, or just count the rows
  if ($return == "rows") {
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
  }
  elseif ($return == "count") {
    return $stmt->rowCount();
  }
```

error

> Warning: Missing argument 4 for sql(), called in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/new.php on line 55 and defined in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/pdo.php on line 19
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/pdo.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/pdo.php(24): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/new.php(55): sql(Object(PDO), 'INSERT INTO mem...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/pdo.php on line 24

what's problem?

Comment: Instead of running your own password hashing algorithm, you should use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). That will make the password hashes stronger, since those functions are built using best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters are already an array when you create the data, so when you pass them as `array($params)`, it nests the data.  So just remove that in your call...

```
sql($db, "INSERT INTO member (pcode, password, name, phone, grade) 
            VALUES (:pcode, :password, :name, :phone, :grade)", 
        $params, "rows" );
```

Not sure what you want the last parameter to be, but I would recommend changing it to something else.  Having a literal like "rows" or "count" can be prone to errors.  Change it to a boolean - something like `true` means return the rows, `false` means a count.

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 4 for sql(), called in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/new.php on line 57 and defined in /home/vvvvvv/html/summit/pdo.php on line 19

Comment: Parameter 4 should either be "rows" or "count", but you don't pass in anything.

Comment: You can also preset parameters, e.g.
`function sql($db, $q, $params, $return='rows')` if you pass the 4th parameter when calling the function it will be overriden.

Comment: @Lupo, this may help, but I still don't like the idea of having strings as a method of indicating how you want the data represented, it's so easy to mistype one time and not find it.

Comment: @NigelRen : I agree and understand your argument very well. I usually define constants like `define('RETVAL_ROWS`, 'rows');` whenever i run into such a method call when maintaining legacy projects. In my opinion `sql($db, $q, $params, RETVAL_ROWS);` is far more readable.

Comment: echo '<td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="삭제"><a href="member_del.php?no="'.$row['pcode'].'""> <button name="delete" id="delete" onclick="return confirm('삭제 하시겠습니까?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></a></td>';  how can i fix it?